# OpenAPI 3.0 file format giving error around allowedValues in parameters

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I've API Spec specified in OAS 3.0

```
post:
  tags:
    - One Time Payment
  summary: One Time Payment API
  operationId: oneTimePaymentUsingPOST
  parameters:
    - in: body
      name: realTimePaymentRequest
      description: realTimePaymentRequest
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/RealTimePaymentRequest'
```

When I edit this spec file in https://editor.swagger.io/ - It's throwing errors as :

```
Structural error at paths./banks/payments.post.parameters.0.in
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: path, query, header, cookie
```

I can see that describing in: body in parameters is supported as per https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/

**thought Swagger Editor is throwing errors. What could be wrong here ? schema ?**

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.0, `in: body` and `in: formData` parameters were replaced with `requestBody`:

```yaml
post:
  tags:
    - One Time Payment
  summary: One Time Payment API
  operationId: oneTimePaymentUsingPOST

  requestBody:
    description: realTimePaymentRequest
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/RealTimePaymentRequest'
```

The documentation link you posted is for OpenAPI 2.0. For OpenAPI 3.0, use this link:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/